# session in a desktop app in java and mysql using eclipse

Tags: java

Am an Aptech student and we are doing a lot of projects and this is one.
Its about bank management and usage. This is my authentication class but i want to include a session:

```
public class AuthenticationFrame {
    public static void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSoft");

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel1.setOpaque(true);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel2.setOpaque(true);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel3.setOpaque(true);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        cons.insets = new Insets(5,3,5,3);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter Your name");
        label1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
        field1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,20));
        field1.setForeground(Color.RED);


        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter Your pin");
        label2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        JPasswordField field2 = new JPasswordField();
        field2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,20));
        field2.setForeground(Color.RED);

        JLabel lb = new JLabel("CB Banking");

        JButton Rdbtn = new JButton("Proceed");
        JButton Bkbtn = new JButton("<<");

        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 0;
        panel1.add(label1, cons);
        cons.gridx = 1;
        cons.gridy = 0;
        panel1.add(field1, cons);

        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 2;
        panel1.add(label2, cons);
        cons.gridx = 1;
        cons.gridy = 2;
        panel1.add(field2, cons);

        cons.gridx = 1;
        cons.gridy = 3;
        panel1.add(Rdbtn, cons);
        panel2.add(lb);
        panel3.add(Bkbtn, BorderLayout.WEST);




        Rdbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                }
                catch(Exception er){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, er.getMessage());
                }

                try{
                    if(field1.getText().equals("") && field2.getText().equals("")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no empty fields");
                    }
                    else{
                        Connection CBcon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankSystem_Db", "root", "elemie");
                        String username = field1.getText();
                        int pin = Integer.parseInt(field2.getText());
                        String query = "SELECT fname, pin FROM usertb WHERE fname = ? AND pin = ?";
                        PreparedStatement CBprep = CBcon.prepareStatement(query);
                        CBprep.setString(1, username);
                        CBprep.setInt(2, pin);

                        ResultSet CBrs = CBprep.executeQuery();
                        int CBresult = 0;
                        while(CBrs.next()){
                            CBresult+=1;
                        }
                        if(CBresult == 1){
                            UserFrame.monitor_three();
                            frame.dispose();
                        }
                        else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect username or password");
                            field1.setText(null);
                            field2.setText(null);
                        }
                        CBrs.close();
                        CBprep.close();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception er){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, er.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }); 

        Bkbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ee){
                Bsystem2.monitor_One();
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null ); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

This part should work like an atm. Get everything about the user in the database. Its suppose to open my userFrame class

Comment: Could you please describe your problem, the approaches you tried and why it is not working; or at least what goes wrong according to you.

Comment: I just want to add a session to hold the the information of a particular user when logged in